# failed: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (2322 > 1280): CPI call

Tags: anchor, cpi

I understand I need to use a versioned tx with lookup tables to reduce the instruction size but how do I do that with a CPI call?

```
    let accounts: Vec<AccountMeta> = ctx
        .remaining_accounts
        .iter()
        .map(|acc| AccountMeta {
            pubkey: *acc.key,
            is_signer: acc.is_signer,
            is_writable: acc.is_writable,
        })
        .collect();

    invoke_signed(
        &Instruction {
            program_id: Jupiter::id(),
            accounts,
            data,
        },
        &ctx.remaining_accounts,
        &[&[
            TRADING_SEED,
            &[ctx.bumps.trader],
        ]],
    )?;
```

For context, I'm calling Jupiter within an anchor program but the call requires too many accounts. The Jupiter api provides lookup tables but I'm not sure how to incorporate the tables into `invoke_signed`

Comment: So, according to the Jupiter docs, what I am trying to do is not possible. Going to work around this by using transaction introspection or their flashfill example
https://station.jup.ag/docs/APIs/cpi

Answer (score 4):

The best you can currently do is to use the Solana Address Lookup Program: https://crates.io/crates/solana-address-lookup-table-program

Then you can read the LUT's keys: https://docs.rs/solana-address-lookup-table-program/1.17.16/solana_address_lookup_table_program/state/struct.AddressLookupTable.html

But if this account needs to be passed to the CPI as AccountInfo (and it probably does), you'll need to create a LUT for your program, pass the accounts there, and pass them along again to the CPI, which you can do entirely on the front end using a versioned tx without the LUT program or changing how your CPI is structured.

You may also find it easier to handle the swap in its own ix rather than by CPI, and handle enforcing any side effects you need to enforce by using Transaction Introspection.

Here's how you might make a LUT on the front end and pass it to your tx to then pass to the CPI:

```
// Create lookup table
        const slot = await provider.connection.getSlot();
        const [createLookupIx, lookupTableKey] =
          AddressLookupTableProgram.createLookupTable({
            authority: wallet.publicKey,
            payer: wallet.publicKey,
            recentSlot: slot - 1,
          });
        await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(
          new Transaction().add(createLookupIx)
        );
        lutKey = lookupTableKey;

        const extendInstruction = AddressLookupTableProgram.extendLookupTable({
          payer: wallet.publicKey,
          authority: wallet.publicKey,
          lookupTable: lookupTableKey,
          addresses: [
            program.programId,
            wallet.publicKey,
            some_key,
            another_key,
          ],
        });

        await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(
          new Transaction().add(extendInstruction)
        );


        // Store addresses in lookup table in chunks
        const maxAddressesPerTransaction: number = 25;
        const numberOfTransactions = Math.ceil(
          some_keys.length / maxAddressesPerTransaction
        );
        for (let k = 0; k < numberOfTransactions; k++) {
          const startIdx = k * maxAddressesPerTransaction;
          const endIdx = startIdx + maxAddressesPerTransaction;
          const addressSubset = some_keys.slice(startIdx, endIdx);

          const extendInstruction = AddressLookupTableProgram.extendLookupTable(
            {
              payer: wallet.publicKey,
              authority: wallet.publicKey,
              lookupTable: lookupTableKey,
              addresses: addressSubset,
            }
          );

          await program.provider.sendAndConfirm(
            new Transaction().add(extendInstruction)
          );
        }

        // You typically have to wait one slot to use a LUT
        await waitUntil(Date.now() / 1000 + 1);

        const lookupTableAcc = (
          await provider.connection.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableKey)
        ).value;
        lutAcc = lookupTableAcc;
        // Debug or use your LUT....
```

Then sending the tx...

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: (await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash())
        .blockhash,
      instructions: [
        await your_ix(
          // ix args...
        ),
      ],
    }).compileToV0Message([lutAcc]);
    const txV0 = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

program.provider.sendAndConfirm(txV0);
```

Comment: oh, transaction inspection is not a bad idea..
do you have any examples of using a LUT with a cpi call? I would rather go that route

Comment: Added a TS example to the answer. You could put like 30+ remaining accounts into the ix like this no problem and pass them to the CPI, but you might also need to request Compute Budget and you might run out of memory too.

Comment: Hi @Whiteseal, how to create TransactionInstruction from anchor solana program methods? program.methods
      .executeTransactions(executeParams)
      .accounts({
        account1: lookupTableAccount[0],
        account2: lookupTableAccount[1],
      })
      .signers([admin])
      .rpc();

Answer (score 1):

Faced this error when I was  using mismatched anchor and solana-program version.

Could you upgrade to the latest versions and try again.

Comment: lol ya I've run into this error before too but that was from some serialization mismatch and the error was more ridiculous like `... instruction too large (2343334 > 1280)`